# Ecological Footprint: United States National Yield 2012

Tags: ecological-footprint

Does ANYONE have (or can point me to a publication that has) the national yields for the Ecological Footprint as calculated by the Global Footprint Network for the United States for the year 2012?

I need the Yield Factors (which I can calculate using the open-source data for world yields) but I am missing the national yields for the United States for the year of 2012 to make my ecological footprint.

I am doing my final project for my undergrad degree in Sustainability. Any help would be greatly appreciated!!!

Comment: Yes I have downloaded this document. Although yield factors/national yields are not included, since I am calculating the impact of electricity geenration (the ecological footprint of production only), in this part of the calculation method used by the GFN, the national yield cancels out in the equation, leaving only the global yield as a variable - this is given tin the National Footprint Accounts dataset!

Thank you for your reply, I believe my project is now do-able.

Answer (score 1):

The Global Footprint Network recently started publishing ecological footprint data free of charge:

> Global Footprint Network’s National Footprint Accounts 2017 Public Data Package is provided at no charge to academics, educators, NGOs, the media, and private and public analysts, as long as they register and clearly indicate and acknowledge the source in every public use of the data ([source](http://www.footprintnetwork.org/licenses/public-data-package-free-edition-copy/))

Their 2017 national footprint accounts dataset is available at https://data.world/footprint/nfa-2017-edition. You'll have to sign-up to get access, but signing up is free. I quickly looked at it and didn't see any yield factors, but perhaps you can calculate them using this data?

Alternatively you can sometimes find older yields and equivalence factors in scientific reports (e.g. see [my answer here](http://sustainability.stackexchange.com/a/5195/99)), but you have to be lucky to find exactly the one you are looking for.